# Can't insert a row to the specific index of datagridview after sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datatable

So, my DGV's datasource is DataTable "table". And when I want to insert a row into it I simply do it like this:

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.InsertAt(row, index);
```

But when I sort the datagridview by clicking on the ColumnHeader, and try to insert afterward - it inserts not at the index, that I wrote, but where the sorting actually puts it. (for example if the row is empty, it will go to index = 0)
I have tried turning off the sorting before inserting:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

But this didn't help. 
The only thing which I found that can handle this is re-creating the DataTable

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

But I can't do this in my program.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Do you think that the datagridview sorting is broken?

Comment: I don't think that it is broken, there just must be a way to turn off sorting (after u have sorted once) somehow, so when u add new rows it doesn't sort them automatic